# Delete Calendar event while uninstall the App from iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an app which will register the calendar events. When you uninstall the application, whether all events created by app deleted automatically? Kindly assist me.

Comment: During uninstalling app, there is no event will get fired from your app. Hence you cannot code such thing in your app. The other thing is, events are created in iOS default calendar app, hence how would it get notified whether my app is there or uninstalled? I think its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

iOS has no way to connect calendar entries to an app, so there's no builtin mechanism.

Your app does not get notified/run when it gets uninstalled, so you cannot cleanup yourself.